# Detect fake user Agents?

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-agent, detect

Is it possible to recover if someone is visiting my website using a fake user agent? If yes, can someone please tell me how can find out this information?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Simple saying no. You can change the user agent and send the modified header.

Comment: `recover`?  Why should your website fall apart because of an invalid user agent?

Comment: What is a fake user agent? If I wrap an IE control in a wrapper and call my new browser `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Mike 1.0; Windows NT 6.3)`, am I lying?

Comment: Can be for statistical purposes, or not showing the page if the user is using some browsers (I have seen that, for luck its for IE users, so it's like true)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: what's a 'fake' user agent? You mean spoofed?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the user agent from PHP like from this global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. But if someone is using a fake user agent which claims to be something else* it's going to be difficult to spot.

This shouldn't really matter unless they are a hacker who is able to find some security weaknesses in your site and use those to do something nasty like access your database, delete all your data or download your users' credit card numbers.

The solution to the hacker problem is make sure your website is secure.

- This is called 'spoofing' as @JAL mentions in his comment above.